# inserting into dynamic / parameterised dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to write a function which inserts matrices along a dimension into an numpy array. Where the dimension is given as a parameter to the function. However, I am struggling with the fact that the dimension shall be dynamic. If I'd know the dimension something like this would work:

```
a = np.ones((2,3,4))
print a
```

> [[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
>
> [[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]]

```
a[:, 0, :] = np.ones((2,4))*2
print a
```

> [[[ 2.  2.  2.  2.]   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
>
> [[ 2.  2.  2.  2.]   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]]

How can I make the dimension I insert the 2x4 (or 2x3, 3x4) matrix dynamic?

In other words, assuming arr.shape = (2,3,4):

```
f(arr, i=1, dim=0)
# this would perform the following:
arr[1, :, :] = np.ones((3,4))*2
```

while

```
f(arr,i=0, dim=2)
# would perform the following:
arr[:,:, 0] = np.ones((2,3))*2
```

PS: the shape determination problem of the matrix which shall be inserted is solved.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I want to have a function where the 0 in the above example can be at parameterised position. So func(a, dim=0) would perform a[0,:,:] = something, and func(a, dim=2) would do a[:,:,0] = something

Comment: Can't you use a[:, b, :] where b is your parameter?

Comment: No this would just insert at the b-th position along a dimension. But would not make the dimension itself variable.

Comment: It's still not quite clear to me what you want. Maybe give us a few input examples and desired outputs?

Comment: I did. see question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the 'set' version of these 'gets':

```
In [155]: arr=np.arange((2*3*4)).reshape(2,3,4)
In [156]: arr[0]
Out[156]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [157]: arr[:,0]
Out[157]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
In [158]: arr[:,:,0]
Out[158]: 
array([[ 0,  4,  8],
       [12, 16, 20]])
```

`np.s_` shows us what one of those index tuples looks like:

```
In [160]: np.s_[:,:,0]
Out[160]: (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), 0)
```

So we could construct that from scratch.  For example with tuple concatenate:

```
In [161]: idx=(slice(None),)*2+(0,)
In [162]: idx
Out[162]: (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), 0)
In [164]: arr[idx]
Out[164]: 
array([[ 0,  4,  8],
       [12, 16, 20]])
```

Is that enough to get you going on a generalized function?

`np.take` lets you index on a specific axis, but I don't think there's a `put` equivalent.  There is a `put`, but it operates on the flat.